# Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln{\left(1-kt^2(1-t)+\frac{t^4(1-t)^2}{4}\right)}}{t}dt$ , where $k=\cos1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, beta-function

I want to find the value of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos n}{n^22^n\binom{3n}{n}}.$

Since $\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{\binom{3n}{n}}=2n\beta(2n,n+1)=2n\int_0^1t^{2n-1}(1-t)^ndt$,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n^2\binom{3n}{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2x^n}{n}\int_0^1t^{2n-1}(1-t)^ndt=\int_0^1\dfrac{2}{t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(x(1-t)t^2)^n}{n}\right)dt$.

Since  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}=-\ln{(1-z)}$, $\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{2}{t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(x(1-t)t^2)^n}{n}\right)dt=-\int_0^1\dfrac{2}{t}\ln{\left(1-x(1-t)t^2\right)}dt$.

Therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n^2\binom{3n}{n}}=-\int_0^1\dfrac{2}{t}\ln{\left(1-x(1-t)t^2\right)}dt$.

If substitute $x=\dfrac{e^i}{2}$ and consider the real part , then
 $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos n}{n^22^n\binom{3n}{n}}=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln{\left(1-kt^2(1-t)+\frac{t^4(1-t)^2}{4}\right)}}{t}dt$, where $k=\cos1$.

Is it possible to find the exact value of this integral?

Thank in advances.

Comment: this integrals can be obtained in the form of dilogarithms. for this one needs the roots of the polynomial inside the $\log$ which is the ugly part here